# Using natbib package, in the References section, the header is now written in capitals

Tags: header-footer, natbib, capitalization

I have a thesis written in LaTeX. I've just switched over to `natbib` as it offered some nice commands but I'm starting to run into some trouble. This one is minor I guess, but I have headers, with the chapter name and page number on. They are implemented in the `.cls` file like so:

```
\def \@oddhead{\normalfont \rmfamily \slshape \hfill \leftmark \hfill \thepage}% writes chapter (not sec) at top.
```

for a normal page, and

```
\def \ps@chapHeadings{\def \@oddhead{\hfill \textit{\thepage}}}
```

for a new chapter page.

Now the reference pages have the headings written all capitals. I don't like this as it's inconsistent with the way the rest of the thesis is done.

Does any one know how to sort it?

Comment: The chapter name is written in `\leftmark`, which is probably made `\MakeUppercase{...}` (or `\uppercase`) somewhere. You do not show this code, but I would suspect removing it would remove the capatilization.

Comment: @Werner: `natbib` defines `\@mkboth` with `\MakeUppercase`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bibsection{%
      \chapter*{\bibname\@mkboth{\bibname}{\bibname}}}
\makeatother
```

You should use `biblatex` instead of `natbib`. It provides the same commands but it is more flexible.

Here a full working example and it works well:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
author={John Smith},
title={TITLE},
year={2011},
publisher={\lipsum\lipsum},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{\normalfont \rmfamily \slshape \hfill \leftmark \hfill \thepage}%
\def\@evenhead{\normalfont \rmfamily \slshape \hfill  \thepage \hfill \rightmark}
 \renewcommand\bibsection{%
      \chapter*{\bibname\@mkboth{\bibname}{\bibname}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\nocite{test}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Here a small extension to list the references in the table of contents:

```
\makeatletter
%not numbered
 \renewcommand\bibsection{%
      \chapter*{\bibname\@mkboth{\bibname}{\bibname}}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
      }
%numbered
% \renewcommand\bibsection{%
%      \chapter{\bibname}\@mkboth{\bibname}{\bibname}
%      }
\makeatother
```

Comment: @Werner: Now you can edit my post ;-)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work right. It replaces the heading with "ReferencesmkbothReferencesReferences" and then write "Conclusions" for the header, which is the previous chapter title.

Comment: I tried biblatex, but it didn't seem to work properly. I have a 253 page document. It threw up abotu 120 errors with unhelpful error messages and told me that most of my bibtex references had problems with them (warnings)

Comment: @aghsmith: I edited my post. Normally `biblatex` can simple replaced [What do to to switch to `biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex).

Comment: Well done sir, some fine hackery. Actually it might have been the \makeatletter command that I kind of knew about... I also added this, which i found on another site, to put references in the contents:  `\let\oldbibsection\bibsection
 \renewcommand{\bibsection}{\oldbibsection\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{References}}`    I just added it after, I'm sure it could have been combined some how though.

Comment: @aghsmith: You can also load the package tocbibind: `usepackage[notoc]{tocbibind}`. Another solution you can find in my edited post (in few minutes)

Comment: A question about this code: Should the first of the two `\hfill` commands in each of the `\@xhead` re-definitions be eliminated? Separately, is it a good idea to set the page numbers in `\slshape`?

Comment: @Mico: The definition of `\@ohead` is taken from your questions. There the page numbers are also slanted.

Comment: @Marco: Just to clarify: I am **not** the OP of this question; I believe aghsmith is that person... All I did was to take your code and run it. That's when I noticed the bizarre look of the header lines caused by the surplus `\hfill` instruction.

Comment: @Mico: Oh Sorry. It was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to remove the header entirely (e.g. because you do not use headers in the rest of the file), just add

`\renewcommand\bibsection{}`

to the preamble.

This should work in all templates working with `natbib`, such as `iopart` (IOP) for example.